# Overloading " < " for STL sort()

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading

I have made a structure containing two variables both of long long int type, say `x` and `y`.

I am able to use the STL `sort()` by overloading the `<` operator and sorting on the based of any one of the variables.

```
struct point
{
    long long int x, y;
};

bool compare(point lhs, point rhs)
{    
    return lhs.x < rhs.x;
}

sort(point, point + t, compare);
```

What I want to do is sort the structure based on `x`, but when two buckets have the same value of `x` then bucket with smaller `y` value should be placed first.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just for the record, you're not doing any overloading of `<` here.

Answer (score 5):

Compare the tuples of `x` and `y`:

```
bool compare(point lhs, point rhs)
{    
    return std::tie(lhs.x, lhs.y) < std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y);
}
```

This does exactly what you want.

A reference page for `std::tie` has even got an example of basically the same thing you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

It would be exactly how you said it:

```
bool compare(point lhs, point rhs)
{    
    return (lhs.x == rhs.x)
         ? (lhs.y < rhs.y)
         : (lhs.x < rhs.x);
}
```

Also, the comparator for `std::sort()` should take const lvalue-references:

```
bool compare(point const& lhs, point const& rhs);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
inline bool compare(const point& lhs, const point& rhs)
{    
   if (lhs.x < rhs.x)
       return true;
   if (lhs.x > rhs.x)
       return false;
   return lhs.y < rhs.y;
}
```